# How to get records length on Datatable in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am getting data in datatable, but i want data count on datatable loading.

```
$('#userdata').DataTable({
        "ajax" : "/searchuser1?emp="+emp,
        "bDestroy":true,
        "columns":[
                    {"data": "empid1"},                                                             
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "phone"},
                    {"data": "logintime"},
                    {"data": "logouttime"}
                   ],

                   "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                   "language": {
                       "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                       "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                       "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                       "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                   },
                   "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                  "lengthChange": false 
        });
```

i tried below way but i don't know where is it write inside datatable

```
var totalRecords =$("#userdata").DataTable().page.info().recordsTotal;
 alert(totalRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $('#userdata').DataTable({
            "ajax" : "/searchuser1?emp="+emp,
            "bDestroy":true,
            "columns":[
                        {"data": "empid1"},                                                             
                        {"data": "name"},
                        {"data": "phone"},
                        {"data": "logintime"},
                        {"data": "logouttime"}
                       ],

                       "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                       "language": {
                           "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                           "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                           "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                           "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                       },
                       "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                      "lengthChange": false 
            });  

            //By methods 
            function getCount(){
              var totalRecords  =$("#userdata").DataTable().page.info().recordsTotal;
             alert(totalRecords);
           }
```

Comment: Where to write this logic. In side datatable method or out side?

Comment: You can write this logic in method or event after the DataTable initiated

Answer (score 0):

Datatable has inbuild function to get length like this

```
var oTable = $('#tblTestResults').DataTable();
oTable.fnGetData().length;  // gives no of record in datable
```